# How to get data like errors by reference?

Tags: php

For example, I have method which return some Boolean data, and I don't want to change it or build some additional service, but I want to get message back if it necessary.

```
class Test
{ 
    
    function action (&$log=null)
    {
        $log = 'Error';
        return true;
    }
}
    
$log = null;
$object = new Test();
$object->action($log);
echo $log;
```

Didn't find some examples, so isn't against of best practice or some other code styles?

Comment: I would suggest to open a separate output stream and to directly log into that from all methods. You can even use output buffering. That way you don't have to go through all the hassle with handing over variables all the time ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that would be to have a private class variable set to null by default and to change its value from the function.

This variable could be accessed from the outside of the class by using a getter.

Comment: This does not tell you _when_ that log entry has been written (by which method call for example).

Comment: Yep! Just don't know why I didn't use it this idea, because used it before also. Thanks for remind me it!

Comment: @arkascha yes.. just in case if we will check return statement